# ctypes and passing a by reference to a function

Tags: python, ctypes, libpcap

I'm trying to use libpcap in python3 using ctypes.

given the following function in C

```
pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf)
```

in python I have the following

```
pcap_lookupnet = pcap.pcap_lookupnet

mask = ctypes.c_uint32
net = ctypes.c_int32

if(pcap_lookupnet(dev,net,mask,errbuf) == -1):
print("Error could not get netmask for device {0}".format(errbuf))
sys.exit(0)
```

and the error i get is

```
  File "./libpcap.py", line 63, in <module>
 if(pcap_lookupnet(dev,net,mask,errbuf) == -1):
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

how do you deal with &blah  values ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to create instances for `net` and `mask`, and use `byref` to pass them.

```
mask = ctypes.c_uint32()
net = ctypes.c_int32()
pcap_lookupnet(dev, ctypes.byref(net), ctypes.byref(mask), errbuf)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow says to avoid using comments like "thanks" but I spent a long time trying to figure out a solution to this issue as well.  So...THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 3):

`ctypes.c_uint32` is a *type*.  You need an instance:

```
mask = ctypes.c_uint32()
net = ctypes.c_int32()
```

Then pass using `ctypes.byref`:

```
pcap_lookupnet(dev,ctypes.byref(mask),ctypes.byref(net),errbuf)
```

You can retrieve the value using `mask.value`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use `ctypes.pointer`, like this:

```
pcap_lookupnet(dev, ctypes.pointer(net), ctypes.pointer(mask), errbuf)
```

See the ctypes tutorial section on [pointers](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) for more information.

I'm assuming you've created ctypes proxies for the other arguments as well.  If `dev` requires a string, for example, you can't simply pass in a Python string; you need to create a `ctypes_wchar_p` or something along those lines.

Comment: net and mask are really specific types   see below int pcap_lookupnet(const char *device, bpf_u_int32 *netp,
               bpf_u_int32 *maskp, char *errbuf);

Comment: bpf_u_int32 is realy just  ...       typedef u_int bpf_u_int32;