# Python call by reference or equivalent

Tags: python, c, ssl, pass-by-reference

I am trying to use SSL library in Python and I need to write a clone code of a C++ code.

In C SSL function is called like this:

```
EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx)
```

In Python I reached SSL library:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
import platform
from os import linesep

libraries = {}

libraries["c"] = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("c"))

if platform.system() != "Windows":
    libraries["ssl"] = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("ssl"))
else:
    libraries["ssl"] = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("libeay32"))

EVP_MD_CTX_init = libraries['ssl'].EVP_MD_CTX_init
EVP_MD_CTX_init.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
EVP_MD_CTX_init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
```

Which is taken from [here](https://seattle.poly.edu/svn/seattle/trunk/tuf/evpy/evp.py)

How may I pass EVP_MD_CTX_init function by reference as it is made in C?
Since I have no access to EVP_MD_CTX_init() method.I have to call this method with 'pass by reference'

I tried EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctypes.byref(mdctx)) but syntax error is occured.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I reopened your question because what I though you were asking for is not actually a duplicate of [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530473/ctypes-and-passing-a-by-reference-to-a-function?lq=1). Then you edited the question to remove everything relevant, so what remains actually _is_ a duplicate again. Why did you do that?

Comment: More to the point: Are you asking how to pass `ctypes` values by reference to C functions, how to pass `ctypes` values by reference to Python functions, or just how to mutate `ctypes` values in Python? They're all different things, and if you ask for the answer to one of those, it will not help you do the others.

Comment: If you want us to debug your code, you have to show us the code and the error you're getting, not just vaguely describe what you tried and what happened. There is no syntax error in the expression `EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctypes.byref(mdctx))`, so most likely your attempt had some _other_ problem, but without seeing it, I can't even begin to guess what. It could have been a missing `)` on the preceding line, a stray non-ASCII character, or a million other things.

Answer (score 2):

You should consult the ctypes [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference).

The way to go is to use `byref()` or `pointer()` (slower and more complex) functions exported by `ctypes` module, as seen in the example.

```
>>> print ctypes.byref.__doc__
byref(C instance[, offset=0]) -> byref-object
Return a pointer lookalike to a C instance, only usable
as function argument
```

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the `ctypes` docs, in [Passing pointers (or: passing by reference)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference):

> Sometimes a C api function expects a pointer to a data type as parameter, probably to write into the corresponding location, or if the data is too large to be passed by value. This is also known as passing parameters by reference.
>
> ctypes exports the `byref()` function which is used to pass parameters by reference. The same effect can be achieved with the `pointer()` function, although `pointer()` does a lot more work since it constructs a real pointer object, so it is faster to use `byref()` if you don’t need the pointer object in Python itself:

```
>>> i = c_int()
>>> f = c_float()
>>> s = create_string_buffer(b'\000' * 32)
>>> print(i.value, f.value, repr(s.value))
0 0.0 b''
>>> libc.sscanf(b"1 3.14 Hello", b"%d %f %s",
...             byref(i), byref(f), s)
3
>>> print(i.value, f.value, repr(s.value))
1 3.1400001049 b'Hello'
```

---

However, now that you're provided the code, you're not trying to pass it to a C function that expects a pointer, you're trying to pass it to a Python function.

If you wanted to do that, as the docs explain, you need to use `pointer` rather than `byref`. And of course the Python function needs to expect a `POINTER(c_int)` rather than a `c_int`.

But in that, you're not even really doing that. You've written this code:

```
a=ctypes.c_int(35)

def foo(n):
    n=ctypes.c_int(19)
```

You're not doing anything to the value that was passed in; you're just rebinding the local name `n` to a different, newly-constructed value.

All you need to do here is change the value:

```
def foo(n):
    n.value = 19
```

Then there's no need for a `byref` or a `pointer` here.

Comment: It does not help because, I want to use it as a paremeter in a function/method.

Comment: @Bhoke: See my edited answer. But since you've edited the question again, I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking anymore.